# Caching disk operations

Tags: python, regex, caching, built-in

I might need to do multiple reads over a big code-base, and with different tools.
I then thought that is a real waste to read on disk so many times while the text won't change, so I wrote the following.

```
class Module(object):
    def __init__(self, module_path):
        self.module_path = module_path
        self._text = None
        self._ast = None

    @property
    def text(self):
        if not self._text:
            self._text = open(self.module_path).read()
        return self._text

    @property
    def ast(self):
        s = self.text  # which is actually discarded
        if not self._ast:
            self._ast = parse(self.text)

        return self._ast


class ContentDirectory(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = {}

    def __getitem__(self, module_path):
        if module_path not in self.content:
            self.content[module_path] = Module(module_path)

        return self.content[module_path]
```

But now it comes the problem, because I would like to avoid changing the rest of the code, while being able to use this new trick.

The only way I see would be to patch the "open" builtin function everywhere it might be used, for example.

```
from myotherlib import __builtins__ as other_builtins
other_builtins.open = my_dummy_open  # which uses this cache
```

But it does not really seem like a wise idea.
Should I just give up and only try if the performance is really too bad maybe?

Comment: "Should I just give up and only try if the performance is really too bad maybe?" - Almost certainly yes.  The OS level will deal with caching files for you.  It's only worth caching if you can do better (e.g. you understand the access patterns better than the OS), but it's always worth seeing if you actually need to do it first.

Comment: How much time does that `parse()` actually take? How many times would it save re-parsing? Could your process / computer be doing something more useful with the memory that the `_ast`s actually take up but aren't being used?

Comment: Well the OS can't do miracles, and from my small tests there is a huge difference in time between the cached and non cached versions, specially if I analyze a lot of files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `mmap` module: http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html

Comment: Thanks interesting this might be quite handy.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the system `open()` call is potentially a bad thing. It requires that everything which uses `open()` uses it as you expect.

Why do you want to avoid changing the code?

Yes, measure the performance and see if it's worthwhile. For example, put in your above code and see how much faster things are. If it's only 1% faster then there's no reason to do anything. If it's significantly faster, then see what's using the `open()` and change that code if you can.

BTW, something like an [LRU cache](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498245-lru-and-lfu-cache-decorators/) (part of [functools](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) in Python 3.2) would also be helpful for your task.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the functionality offered by this library is of any use in your scenario, but thought to mention nevertheless the existence of the [`linecache` library](http://docs.python.org/library/linecache.html). From the linked docs:

> The linecache module allows one to get any line from any file, while attempting to optimize internally, using a cache, the common case where many lines are read from a single file.

...of course this doesn't come even close to your problem of implementing a solution in an elegant and transparent way...